# Autofac resolve IEnumerable<TComponent> for instantiated items only

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Does autofac provide me with a way to get all "active" instances of a component?
So that the following works:

```
public class ViewManager {

    public ViewManager(Func<IEnumerable<MyView>> viewProvider, Func<string, MyView> viewFactory) {
        ViewProvider = viewProvider;
        ViewFactory = viewFactory;
    }

    public Func<IEnumerable<MyView>> ViewProvider { get; private set; }
    public Func<string, MyView> ViewFactory { get; private set; }

    public MyView GetView(string viewId) {
        var existing = from view in ViewProvider() //this would get me all the active views (not the available implementations)
                       where !view.IsDisposed
                             && view.Id == viewId
                       select view;
        return existing.FirstOrDefault() ?? ViewFactory(viewId);
    }
}

public class MyView: IDisposable {
    public MyView(string id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }
    public void Dispose() {
        IsDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box I'm afraid - you'll need to come up with another scheme for this scenario. You might be able to use the `OnActivated()` and `OnRelease()` events to keep your own registry of active views:

```
builder.RegisterType<ViewRegistry>()
  .As<IViewRegistry>()
  .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<MyView>()
  .OnActivated(e =>
     e.Context.Resolve<IViewRegistry>().Add(e.Instance))
  .OnRelease(e => {
     e.Instance.Dispose();
     e.Context.Resolve<IViewRegistry>().Remove(e.Instance))
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I've pretty much resorted to something like this already using my own cache. Is OnRelease only called when the parent container is disposed, or are there other ways to force components to be released?

Comment: To release components ahead of the container you need to use either `BeginLifetimeScope()` or `Owned<T>` - http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OwnedInstances